# How to add the onfocus event to custom created control in jquery?

Tags: jquery, custom-controls

I have a custom created combobox control created using jquery library, where I have textbox wrapped over dropdown control, so that everytime when I use want to use this combobox control, I actually call its object. Now I want to hook the onfocus function of the usual textbox to this custom control. So how could I do this? Relevant answers are appreciated & welcome from my bottom heart!

Comment: relevant code is appreciated in question

Answer (score 0):

Please check the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/z2y6T/

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>span {display:none;}</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><input type="text" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<p><input type="password" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<script>
$("input").focus(function () {
  $(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery Focus**

> Bind an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, or trigger that
>   event on an element

More Info :http://api.jquery.com/focus/